# Placing Object in between string renders [object Ojbect]?

Tags: jquery, html

I am not really good in javascript so forgive me if I am confusing Object between other terms. The Object here is the HTML element. I don't know why my it is rendered as `[object HTMLImageElement]` when placed in between strings. Here's my code:

```
this.elem.find('img').map(function(index, elem){
    markup += '<li>' + elem + '</li>';
});
```

It looks for images in a given container and wraps it with `<li>`. What should I do so that the actual image markup is rendered instead?

Comment: `http://api.jquery.com/wrap/` sounds like the thing you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elem in your code points to the object that is of type ImageElement.

To access the value of the properties/attributes this element has you need to access the properties/attributes.

let say if it has a property named 'value' acess using elem.value

To ger the image markup i think elem.innerHTML should work. You can find better alternative in intellisense if this doesnt work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I hope there's an easier and straightforward way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

```
markup += '<li>' + elem.html() + '</li>';
```